# alpha-numeric identifier causing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, alphanumeric

I am using a basic identifier which uses a unix timestamp with an appended alphanumeric section appended to it.

Everything has been working fine until recently - a couple of identifiers fail to update in the database.

I have noticed that the failing id's have all numbers and the letter E.

EG 1386953039E87 which is being transcribed as 1.386953039e+96

I am far from being a mathematician but feel that the original value is being treated as a number. I have tried using the toString() function but this has not worked for me.

Comment: share code showing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling toString is too late because outputting 1386953039E87 has already created it as a number (or JavaScript's best guess at a number).

Try modifying your server-side code to output it surround in quotes instead, so that it gets created as a string instead of a number.

This could also be a side-effect of using jQuery's data() function. They mention in [their api docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) that it doesn't alter their value but it seems like your situation is proving otherwise:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value
>   is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's
>   representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as
>   numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their
>   representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is
>   converted to the number 100.
>
> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array
>   (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string;
>   it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If
>   the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a
>   string.
>
> To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to
>   convert it, use the attr() method.

So it seems you need to use the attr() instead of data() for this

Comment: I have written the id into a html data element - this has rendered as it should. It seems to change state when it is pulled from the data element via jQuery and added to the page.

Comment: The id is firstly via jquery being added to a data attribute after an ajax request to the server - this renders fine when checked in firebug. I then access the data attribute to write to the page and set a variable using jquery as follows `var job=$(this).data('job_id'); $('.job_pc').text(job); var data="job_id="+job;` I don't know if this helps :)

Comment: interesting, so coming out of $(this).data('job_id') it is becoming 1.386953039e+96?

Comment: out of curiosity, which version of jquery are you using?